# MSSql returns only Resource id #3 response on echo sqlsrv_query()

Tags: php, sql-server

Getting the same kinda issue with all of my apis..
On echo sqlsrv_query(); gives the response Resource id #3.
Also cant find any way to see whether the data returned is empty or not..
May be because of the Resource id #3 response my query data is hampered.
Please do help.

Below is my code.

```
<?php
// the connection part of the code.......
$connectionInfo = array( 
    "UID"=>$uid,"PWD"=>$pwd,"Database"=>$databaseName,"CharacterSet" => "UTF-8");   

/* Connect using SQL Server Authentication. */    
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo); 
if( $conn === false ) {
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$username= $_REQUEST['username'];
$password= $_REQUEST['password'];

if($username && $password)
{
    $query = "SELECT NAME,LOGINID,PASSWORD FROM SMS_ACCESS WHERE LOGINID = '$username' AND   PASSWORD = '$password'";
    /* Execute the query. */    
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn,$query);    
    $json = array(); 

    echo $stmt;

    if ( $stmt === false)    
    {       
        $json["status_code"] = "203";
        $json["status"] = "Error in execution";
            //echo "Error in statement execution.\n";    
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));    
        echo json_encode(['data'=>[$json]]);
    }     
    else     
    {    
        while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt,  SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) 
        {
            $json["name"] = $row['0'];
        }
            //echo json_encode(['status_code' => "200",'status' => "success",'data'=>[$json],'Msg' => "Login Successful !!"]);
    }    
}
else {
    $json["status_code"] = "203";
    $json["status"] = "Parameter Missing !!";   
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  
    echo json_encode(['data'=>[$json]]);
}

/* Free statement and connection resources. */    
sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);    
sqlsrv_close( $conn);    
?>
```

Comment: Are you storing passwords as plain text?

Comment: nope the pwd is encrypted..

Comment: @MattGibson I knew I was forgetting something!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [read the documentation](http://php.net/sqlsrv_query) you'll find that `sqlsrv_query` returns "a statement resource on success and `FALSE` if an error occurred." You can't print a resource, so this behaviour is expected.

Next, you aren't actually outputting any JSON, which might explain why you're having problems with the APIs. [`die`](https://php.net/die) stops program execution immediately.

If you were outputting JSON, you're sending it with the [wrong content type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/477816/1255289), and you're sending it in an inconsistent format. The error conditions have `status` and `status_code` inside a `data` element, while success does not.

You're [fetching your database query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php) as an associative array but then trying to use a numeric index to get a column value. As well, you don't need to loop over the result if you're only getting a single row.

Finally, you open yourself up to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/601524/1255289) by blindly inserting user-provided data into your query. This is a very bad idea, and will allow anyone to log in without authentication.

Try something like this instead:

```
<?php
$connectionInfo = [ 
    "UID"          => $uid,
    "PWD"          => $pwd,
    "Database"     => $databaseName,
    "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8",
];

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo); 
if ($conn === false) {
    $data = [
        "status_code" => "203",
        "status"      => "Database error",
    ];
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
}

$username= $_REQUEST['username'];
$password= $_REQUEST['password'];

if(empty($username) || empty($password)) {
    $data = [
        "status_code" => "203",
        "status"      => "Parameter Missing !!",
    ];
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
}

$query = "SELECT NAME FROM SMS_ACCESS WHERE LOGINID = ? AND PASSWORD = ?";
$parameters = [$username, $password];
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $parameters);
if ($stmt === false) {       
    $data = [
        "status_code" => "203",
        "status"      => "Error in execution",
    ];
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
}
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt);
$data = [
    "status_code" => "200",
    "status"      => "success",
    "data"        => [
        "name"    => $row[0]
    ],
];
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($data);

sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);    
sqlsrv_close($conn);
```

Comment: hey hi this works fine..thanx for your help..but if im entering the wrong values of username or pwd the api is still returning success instead of failure..

Comment: i wana see whether the pwd or username are matching or not..if they arent then api should return failure as reponse...

Comment: So check for an empty result set. Look at number of rows.